# Enable all disabled commands permanently

Tags: emacs

I want to enable all disabled commands in Emacs such as `downcase-region` - that is, when invoked they do not ask confirmation from user. Unfortunately section "48.3.11 Disabling Commands" of Emacs manual says nothing on enabling *all* disabled commands *permanently*.

Emacs version: 24.0.95.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As written in [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DisabledCommands), you can add `(setq disabled-command-function nil)` to your init file, to enable all disabled commands:

Answer (score 2):

Copy such elisp into your `~/.emacs`:

```lisp
(put 'set-goal-column 'disabled nil)
(put 'narrow-to-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'downcase-region 'disabled nil)
(put 'scroll-left 'disabled nil)
(put 'erase-buffer 'disabled nil)
```

Comment: what is the difference between this and, for example, `(setq erase-buffer nil)`?

Comment: The difference, I think, is between the *value* of the symbol, and the symbol's *property list*: http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_symbol_plist.html. Your `setq` is assigning the value `nil` to `erase-buffer`; above, the `put` is, well, putting the property name `disabled` with value `nil` into the property list for each of those symbols.