# How to silent disabled commands?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I want to **silent disabled commands** in Emacs. Possibly unbind them altogether.

When I slip on a disabled-command binding (e.g. <kbd>a</kbd> in `Dired`) — which I am not allowing because I don't want to use it — I'd like it to fail silently, instead of having me cancel what I didn't intend to do. On a per-command basis would be nice, but I don't mind removing them all.

I'm aware of [Enable all disabled commands permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026221/enable-all-disabled-commands-permanently), but I'm after *disabling* them permanently. I could unbind them one by one, I guess, but that would mean [sourcing what map they're defined in](https://superuser.com/questions/506381/how-to-source-key-translations-in-emacs), which I cannot do (apart from being a hassle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
(setq disabled-command-function 'ignore)
```

Then the disabled keys are ignored, nothing happens when you hit, e.g., `C-x n n`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. (Actually, I do use `narrow-to-region` ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Because I was annoyed a couple of times that I hit `C-x C-c` by mistake, I made a function:

```
(defun not-anymore ()
"For overwriting wrong keybindings"
  (interactive)
  (message "not anymore")
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") 'not-anymore)
```

You could just omit the message line, ofcourse.

This allows you to exclude commands as you choose.

Comment: Riiight, that's an option, but it messes up overrides by local maps in some cases, I guess ? (And there's still every single one to disable by hand in `.emacs`.)

Comment: except that you could override those local maps? and yea, but I thought that was what you were after: whenever a command bothers you, you exclude it?

Comment: True enough, **this has the advantage of knowing what you're skipping, and doing it on a per-command basis**. +1. I accept sds' answer for peace of mind, though. The perfect answer would be a "shut up" case in the disabled-command's menu : *don't do it, and never offer me to do it anymore*, which would *automatically* disable it forever.